# How to get all combinations from array python

Tags: python

How to create all possible combinations from the elements of the array of certain length
For instance
N = 6 (length)
arr = ['11'] (mean 11 are adjacent)
Output:

```
110000
011000
001100
000110
000011
100001
```

If arr = ['1','1'] (mean, 11 couldn't be adjacent)
N = 6 (length)
Output:

```
101000
100100
100010
010100
010010
010001
001010
001001
000101
```

I have the following function, but I don't know how to do the combination to be considered adjacent

```
100001
```

Code

```
def f(arr, N, start=''):
    arr1 = arr[1:]
    alen = sum(map(len, arr1)) + len(arr1) - 1
    if (alen):
        alen += 1
    for i in range(N - alen - len(arr[0]) + 1):
        add = '0' * i + arr[0]
        if (arr1):
            f(arr1, N - len(add) - 1, start + add + '0')
        else:
            print(start + add + '0' * (N - len(add)))


arr = ['11']
N = 6
f(arr, N)
```

Comment: Why list `100001` if you are trying to list the combinations where `11` are adjacent?

Comment: @JohnColeman, because I want to emulate that my list doesn't have bounds as if these numbers are written in a circle

Comment: Is it always `0` and a certain number of `1`?

Comment: Yes, saying roughly, It'll be only 11, which are adjacent, and 11, which are not adjacent, and only the length will be changed (e.g 5,6,7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please test

```py
check = []
check2 = []
for x in range(5):
    arr = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    list_of_one_poz = []
    arr[x] = 1
    for y in range(x, 5):
        list_of_one_poz.append(y+1)

    for i in list_of_one_poz:
        arr[i] = 1
        txt = ''.join(str(e) for e in arr)
        r_index = txt.rindex('1')
        l_index = txt.index('1')
        l = list(range(l_index+1, r_index))
        for p in l:
            arr[p]=0
        if r_index - l_index <=1:
            check.append(''.join(str(e) for e in arr))
        elif r_index - l_index == 5:
            check.append(''.join(str(e) for e in arr))
        else:
            check2.append(''.join(str(e) for e in arr))

print(check)
print("")
print(check2)
```

Comment: It works, but it pushes everything to one array, both adjacent, and not adjacent
But I need them separately 
```
['110000', '101000', '100100', '100010', '100001', '011000', '010100', '010010', '010001', '001100', '001010', '001001', '000110', '000101', '000011']
```

Comment: please check it now.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/miNPuLGEbTrL
the same error I faced, I described it in the task 

100001, has to be in adjacent array
I want to emulate that my list doesn't have bounds as if these numbers are written in a circle

Comment: check it now, I added simple if which check if `r_index - l_index == 5` if your list will be longer,  you have to change it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).